# getsockopt with int64_t type returns overflow result

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

I am reading the size of my socket buffer:

```
int buf_size;
socklen_t opt_size = sizeof(buf_size);
getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &buf_size, &opt_size);
```

This ^ works. I get ~130k

However, if I change the type of `buf_size` to `int64_t` this doesn't work:

```
int64_t buf_size;
socklen_t opt_size = sizeof(buf_size);
getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &buf_size, &opt_size);
```

`buf_size` outputs `140733193519104`

Is it possible to use getsockopt and setsockopt with 64 bit integers?

I ask because I want to use `setsockopt()` with a `uint64_t`

Comment: And the obvious solution of passing a pointer to `int`, and after returning simply converting it to a `uint64_t` would not work for you why, exactly? `getsockopt` is a C library function and not a typesafe C++ function, that requires the caller (in this case) to pinky-swear that the last parameter is a pointer to an `int`.

Comment: From the docs, it must be an `int` for `SO_RCVBUF`, so I guess you will not be allowed to set a buffer larger than an `int` can hold. To be honest, the max `int` size of some 2 Gb seems like it *should* be enough for a buffer...

Comment: @NickGris that was my worry.... I guess if I really wanted to I could achieve this by setting the min buffer size on the command line.

Comment: @NickGris So Sam is completely wrong?

Comment: @intrigued_66: You can certainly use an `int` for _`getSockOpt()`_ and cast it up to a `uint64_t` [afterwards], but if you were hoping to use a much larger buffer, you simply wouldn't be able to get that into `setSockOpt()`...